# Outputting MySQL results

Tags: mysql

So I have 3 tables:

```
student
-studentid
-studentname

course_offerings
-course_offeringid
-course
-type

scores
-student_studentid
-course_offering_course_offeringid
-score
```

When I do my query:

```
SELECT studentid, studentname, course, type, score
FROM scores
INNER JOIN student ON scores.student_studentid = student.studentid
INNER JOIN course_offering ON scores.course_offering_course_offeringid = course_offering.course_offeringid
```

I get an output of something like:

```
studentid   studentname     course  type    score
123345      Doe, John       123     Exam 1  100
123345      Doe, John       123     Exam 2  95
123345      Doe, John       123     Exam 3  75
123345      Doe, John       123     Final   93
543211      Doe, Jane       123     Exam 1  70
543211      Doe, Jane       123     Exam 2  91
543211      Doe, Jane       123     Exam 3  99
543211      Doe, Jane       123     Final   43
.
.
.
```

What I would like is for the output to be:

```
studentid   studentname     course  Exam 1  Exam 2  Exam 3  Final
123345      Doe, John       123     100     95       75     93
543211      Doe, Jane       123     70      91      99      43
```

Is this possible with just MySQL?

Comment: i think its possible..May i ask if that's the complete table structure that you have? i think you're missing studentid on both course_offering and scores tables.

Comment: I think there _is_ a studentid in `scores` and there is no reason to have it in the `offerings` table.

Comment: yes, i believe that's right. sorry about that. i also suggest that you remove "type" field and place it on the "scores" table.

Answer (score 0):

Not without hardcoding the amount of exams. You could take the students, join them on your exams 3 different times, making sure that the `first id < secondid < thirdid`  to stop doubles from happening.

If you need an extra exam, or someone has only 2 exams, you would need to deal with it. This sort of pivot isn't possible without hardcoding the 3 (or more / less) joins

Answer (score 0):

Well, SQL won't let you do this, so it's probably better to just perform this processing in your application.

If you *really* want to do this in MySQL, you can use [stored routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) which are slightly more powerful than plain SQL (e.g. you can use a [`FOR`-loop](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop.html)).